# How to prevent duplicate records being created, but all other before_create methods to run?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

A Rails app has an Event and Vote model. Events should be unique.

If a User attempts to create an Event that already exists, save should be prevented, and instead a Vote should be created for the existing Event.

I can prevent the Event from being saved using a custom validation or a `before_create` action. However, this also prevents the `create_vote_on_existing_event` method from being run.

Is there a way to selectively run methods when `before_create` returns false?

My models look something like this

```
class Event
  has_many :votes
  before_create :check_event_is_unique
private
  def check_event_is_unique
    if Event.where( attributes_to_match).any?
      errors.add(:base, :duplicate)
      create_vote_on_existing_event
      return false
    end
  end

  def create_vote_on_existing_event
    event = Event.where( attributes_to_match).last
    self.user.vote_on event 
  end
end
class Vote
  belongs_to :event
end
```

Comment: Andy, it looks like you should turn responsibilities around. I would try to use the Vote model to create a new event if required during voting, though, it really depends on your implementation. It is possible to force things the way you want it, but I think it will be kinda awkward.

Answer (score 1):

You need a custom validator. Something like this might be suitable:

```
class Event
    validate :check_event_is_unique, :on => :create
    after_create :create_vote_on_existing_event

    def check_event_is_unique
      if Event.where( attributes_to_match).any?
          errors.add(:base, :duplicate)
          return false
      end
    end
end
```

You can also have your `after_create` for other methods.

More information on custom validation methods can be found here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#custom-methods

EDIT:
One option is to pass validate: false to the save method. [api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations.html](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations.html)

Another option is `after_validation`. This could call your `create_vote_on_existing_event` if your validation fails. The order of callbacks is as follows:
 
before_validation
after_validation
before_save
before_create
after_create
after_save
after_commit

`after_validation` is the last thing to run if validations fail, so you should be able to run some code from there.

Comment: thanks @dawcars, I had tried something along these lines but could not get it working. If this validation fails, won't it "rewind" `create_vote_on_existing_event`?

Comment: Surely you only want to create a vote if the event exists? Do you not need an `after_create` action for the `create_vote_on_existing_event`?

Comment: One option is to pass `validate: false` to the save method. http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations.html

Comment: I don't think `after_create` will work in this case. I have Event A, a user then tries to create Event B with similar attributes. Rather than creating Event B, instead a vote should be added to Event A. As the Event B create is stopped by the validation, `after_create` will not run.

Comment: Perhaps `after_validation` would work then? `after_validation` could call your `create_vote_on_existing_event` if your validation fails